# How to change the coordinate's system origin in VTK system?

Tags: c++, opengl, vtk

As far as I know vtk's coordinate system origin is the lower left corner. (correct me if I am wrong).

I would like to change my x, y, z coordinates so that they are visualized as the origin would be the upper left corner.

Do you know how should I change them?

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand you clearly, but here is my tip: Invert the coordinate value what represent the vertical axis.

Hope you find this useful :)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm right, you should achieve that just by "flipping" the camera along the Y axis. This could be done through the SetViewUp() method:

```
vtkCamera * camera = myRenderer->GetActiveCamera();
camera->SetViewUp(0, -1, 0);
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah. I used it. Success. :D thanks. But i have a problem. When I use mouse interaction, Is camera of Render changed?

Comment: @HoangAnhTuan: In pure theory, no. Once the renderer camera has been set, its coordinate system should persist. However, I have never tried that :-( I recommend to achieve some test and check if the coordinate system remains the same after each "critical" change. I hope it will work! :-)

Comment: I want to change screen coordinate system sync with vtk coordinate system (Descartes coordinate system). I see, we have 2 way to do it. Either Change camera of myRenderer or move my Thing (convert). I feel the first way to easy :D